# using c++20 concepts to find nth element of parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, parameter-pack

I am looking for a non-recursive, modern method (which compiles, at least with gcc and clang) for finding the <sup>th</sup> element of a variadic parameter pack. Indeed, it would seem such a solution, using c++20 concepts, exists: Kris Jusiak gave a talk *nth pack element* at CppCon, CppNow, and Meeting Cpp, all 2022 and all found on YouTube; Alex Dathskovsky wrote a LinkedIN post *Nth element variadic pack extraction* (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nth-element-variadic-pack-extraction-alex-dathskovsky-); and surely there are other places this may be found. Both solutions are fairly similar, both purportedly perform very well; I will include the former below. Sadly **neither** of the mentioned examples compiles. Here is the compiler explorer link given in Jusiak's talk (https://godbolt.org/z/WPhe5MerW), and below is a copy:

```
#include <cstddef> // adding #include <concepts> changes nothing
#include <utility>

template <typename, std::size_t> concept prefix = true;

template <auto N>
constexpr auto nth_element(auto... args) {
  return [&]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return [] (prefix<Is> auto..., auto arg, auto...) {
      return arg;
    }(args...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1));
static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1, 2));
static_assert(2 == nth_element<1>(1, 2));        // this line throws an error
static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1, 2, 3));
static_assert(2 == nth_element<1>(1, 2, 3));     // and this one
static_assert(3 == nth_element<2>(1, 2, 3));     // and this one
```

This doesn't compile locally, nor on godbolt. Comments are my own. Here's what `gcc`s complaints boil down to:

```
<source>:10:27: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'prefix<auto:2, Is>'
   9 |     return [] (prefix<Is> auto..., auto arg, auto...) {
```

and `clang`s:

```
<source>:9:31: note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: pack expansion
contains parameter packs 'auto:1' and 'Is' that have different lengths (0 vs. 1)
    9 |     return [] (prefix<Is> auto..., auto arg, auto...) {
```

This seems to be causing a "constraints not satisfied" so that the template argument deduction/substitution fails, leading to no matching (function) call for the nested lambda in line 9.

Well I tried searching around, to no avail. Not sure if it is because **disclaimer** I'm not a professional, or if it's truly a bit tricky! I do not know what to do. I tried silly things like adding and removing ellipsis here and there, like `std::size_t...` in the prefix concept, or `prefix<Is...>` in our problematic lambda, but neither helped. The LinkedIN post and the conference talk try to break it down as well, which I hoped to digest enough to be able to come up with a fix – not the case. Sincerely I apologize for not having a better attempt to offer. Yes, other working solutions exist and some may be found in the aforementioned sources, but I am particularly interested in getting one of these which uses concepts to compile.

I also found some potentially useful and relevant SO posts, none of which I could figure out how to use to help. Many offer recursion as the solution.

- Mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding std::index_sequence and variadic argument pack (see questions/74805917/mismatched-argument-pack-lengths-while-expanding-stdindex-sequence-and-variadi)
- How to Iterate over a parameter pack (see questions/71985500/how-to-iterate-over-a-parameter-pack)
- How can I iterate over a packed variadic template argument list? questions/7230621/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-packed-variadic-template-argument-list
- template parameter packs access Nth type and Nth element (see questions/20162903/template-parameter-packs-access-nth-type-and-nth-element)
- C++: candidate template ignored when iterating over tuple (see questions/68299663/c-candidate-template-ignored-when-iterating-over-tuple)

Any guidance or help with this would be greatly appreciated!

---

Now, perhaps this post is too long by now, and the following may be more appropriate as a (separate) follow-up question, but in Andrei Alexandrescu's CppCon 2021 talk *Embracing (and also Destroying) Variant Types Safely* (found on YouTube) he suggests adding the following to the standard for help in dealing with parameter packs:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct type_sequence {};
//
template<typename... Ts> struct head;
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct head<type_sequence<T, Ts...>>
{
  using type = T;
};
template<typename T>
using head_t = typename head<T>::type;
//
template<typename... Ts> struct tail;
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tail<type_sequence<T, Ts...>>
{
  using type = type_sequence<Ts...>;
};
template<typename T>
using tail_t = typename tail<T>::type;
//
template<typename T, typename List> struct cons;
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct cons<T, type_sequence<Ts...>>
{
  using type = type_sequence<T, Ts...>;
};
template<typename T, typename List>
using cons_t = typename cons<T, List>::type;
```

and I wondered if in the concept-expansion solution for finding the <sup>th</sup> element in a pack, we might be able to find a way to replace `std::index_sequence` with this `type_sequence`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: thank you – this duplicate question did not show up when I was searching or about to post. I wouldn't have asked otherwise...

Answer (score 3):

This much simpler function satisfies all your tests shown (and also a test with hybrid types). What I cannot tell you is if this meets your compile time requirements for speed (I assume the standard library implementers will have done a good enough job)

"concepts" do not even come into play at all since there is no need to constrain the template in any way.

```
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto nth_element(auto... args)
{
    return std::get<N>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1));
    static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1, 2));
    static_assert(2 == nth_element<1>(1, 2));        // this line throws an error, ok now
    static_assert(1 == nth_element<0>(1, "Hello", 3.0));
    static_assert(2 == nth_element<1>(1, 2, 3));     // and this one, ok now
    static_assert(3 == nth_element<2>(1, 2, 3));     // and this one, ok now
}
```